# How to create a sound from scratch using formant synthesis in Java?

Tags: java, signal-processing

Is there any example Java program, that creates sound, like using Math.sin or something to create sound if I pass f1 and f2 (frequency) parameters of formant?

Comment: yes, i googled , but still cant understand how to ...

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932490/java-generating-sound

Comment: i want to know if if i pass two frequencies f1 and f2 of formant, then how the sound will be generated

Comment: In the link of the answer I passed you there is an example of generating a sound.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1273219?start=0&tstart=0).

```
/** Generates a tone.
  @param hz Base frequency (neglecting harmonic) of the tone in cycles per second
  @param msecs The number of milliseconds to play the tone.
  @param volume Volume, form 0 (mute) to 100 (max).
  @param addHarmonic Whether to add an harmonic, one octave up. */
  public static void generateTone(int hz,int msecs, int volume, boolean addHarmonic) throws LineUnavailableException {

    float frequency = 44100;
    byte[] buf;
    AudioFormat af;
    if (addHarmonic) {
      buf = new byte[2];
      af = new AudioFormat(frequency,8,2,true,false);
    } else {
      buf = new byte[1];
      af = new AudioFormat(frequency,8,1,true,false);
    }
    SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
    sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
    sdl.open(af);
    sdl.start();
    for(int i=0; i<msecs*frequency/1000; i++){
      double angle = i/(frequency/hz)*2.0*Math.PI;
      buf[0]=(byte)(Math.sin(angle)*volume);

      if(addHarmonic) {
        double angle2 = (i)/(frequency/hz)*2.0*Math.PI;
        buf[1]=(byte)(Math.sin(2*angle2)*volume*0.6);
        sdl.write(buf,0,2);
      } else {
        sdl.write(buf,0,1);
      }
    }
    sdl.drain();
    sdl.stop();
    sdl.close();
  }
```

Comment: may be this would help ,if i would be able understand this line `Math.sin(2*angle2)*volume*0.6` ?